# Ionic 2 - How to validate whether the user is already purchased the item on App launch

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2, in-app-purchase

I am using [In-App purchase plugin](https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase) to do the In App purchases from my App. it's non-consumable product so I tried to restore the purchase on every App launch but binary is rejected as we should provide separate button for restore purchases.

How we have to check whether the user has already purchased the item on App launch?

Comment: Don't you have a back-end (database) which contains your users and more .. ?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS you must call getReceipt() then send this information to https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt (production) or https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt (non-published app) with HTTP. Then validate the response for the purchase. More [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html)

You shouldn't call getReceipt() every load as it will ask the user to login. Rather store the purchase info in local storage or a database. If the user changes devices they can restore the purchase.